# claim mapping of standard essential patent

Tags: standards, essential, mapping

Can a patent claim be mapped with two standard documents? In particular, can a particular feature of claim be mapped with two standard documents?

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to add more info for us to answer. What do you mean by "mapped with two standard documents"?

Comment: For example, feature A of claim 1 is mapped with one version of standard document and feature B of claim 1 is mapped with an updated version of standard document. Is there any issue in this type of mapping in standard essential patent case

Comment: By a standard document you mean an industry standard like one from an ISO, ANSI, IEEE, DIN ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this. I think you mean standards documents. A single feature in a claim, by itself is not protected independent of all the other features in the claim. Only the claim as a whole is protected.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is “can one patent be essential for making two different things that require a different standard to be followed”, then yes.

Narrowing the question to a single claim of the patent didn’t change the answer and, as EricS stated, one limitation of a claim has no legal significance on its own.